# Is the Touches works on UITableView and UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am implementing an application that displays a list of items one by one. In that I have a view with UITableView and UIScrollView. When I swipe any point of that view I need to load previous / next items details.

For this I am TouchBegan and TouchEnd functions to know what Item (previous / next) should we load. But this swiping is not working when I swipe on UITableView and UIScrollView. Is there any way to make this work? Please suggest.

Thank you,
Sekhar.

Comment: without seeing your code - in esp your screen structure - I can only guess. possibly the event gets caught by a view that does not handle the touches. make sure that all the primary shown elements catch the touches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subclass UIScrollView to make it detect touches. UIScrollView doesn't handle touches directly.

Have a look at this link to kno how to implement this.

[Link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/9213-detect-touch-scrollview-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

this code may help you create scrollview with Draggable images object and try

```
@interface DraggableImages : UIScrollView {


}


@implementation DraggableImages
@synthesize delegate;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {


    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

      return self;
}


//called when we touch the box
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    // Retrieve the touch point


}
//called when we move box

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

}
//called when touch is cancelled
-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}

//called when touch is ended
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


}
```